# How to get speed up data getting by ignoring empty cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I've ran into a problem with a processing tool I'm working on, namely with the initial hang time being close to 10 seconds long. The issue I'd identified is that when the data is originally Imported into the it proceeds to update every lookup array and function in the 5x1000 workspace. I've been thinking that a good way to speed up the processing was to limit the import to non-empty cells only but have been unable to get it done no matter what I tried.

By default this is the function that imports the data from the RadGridExport temp file into a buffer sheet for later processing:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Workbooks("RadGridExport.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1000")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
End Sub
```

I have attempted to use IsEmpty(Cell.Value) method but that was less than effective

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Workbooks("RadGridExport.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1000")
    For Each Cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

In fact it froze the entire workbook. That was the only way I'm familiar with that could have applied, so I'm in a bit of a dead end.

Is there a way to actually get my initial function to ignore empty cells? Or am I coming at this from the wrong way and there's some method for keeping the worksheet from doing a full update on every single cell, including those whose value doesn't change?

Comment: turn the calculations off at the beginning and then turn them back on at the end.

Comment: And don't runn it on a fixed range `A1:E1000` instead find the last used row dynamically like: `LastUsedRowInA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` so it runs only on cells that actually have data.

Comment: Also try `Set rng = Workbooks("RadGridExport.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1000").SpecialCells(2)`. You can clear your `If IsEmpty....` that way. Somewhat less code. However not much of a speed improvent I think (depends on how many empty cells/gaps in your data you iterate through). Even better is to combine with @Pᴇʜ his comment about a dynamic range.

Comment: Your loop does the same thing ~5000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my problem.

First of all thank to @Pᴇʜ for an way to do dynamic ranges - I ended up not using it in this tool as a lot of processing relies on static cells in a range for auto calculations, but I have written it down for the future!

@JvdV 's suggestion worked like a charm, bringing the load time down from 31 seconds to 14 seconds average.

Current codes looks like this:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Workbooks("RadGridExport.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1:E1000").SpecialCells(2)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
End Sub
```

However it was still forcing a full refresh on all static values - so after digging deeper I realized that I was using a massively taxing clear gate in the main macro:

```
Sub clearAll()
    Range("A:E").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Which caused that massive 14 second delay. After I changed that function to this:

```
Dim Workspace As Range
Set Workspace = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:E1000")

For Each Cell In Workspace
    If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = False Then
    Cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next Cell
```

The load time went down further from 14 seconds to under 2 seconds total.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer as solution (after one day I think).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ 48 hours :) Was just about to do that, thanks once again for your help!